# Abort insert if the insert date is same day as another row with same id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to postgresql and dont know what the best way to do this would be.

I have a table with conserts, all conserts have an band id(INTEGER) and a start date(TIMESTAMP).

I want to make sure to only be able to insert a new consert with same band id as other conserts if the time between them is > 24 hours.

Shorter: A band should only be able to play in a consert every 24 hours.

Is it best to create some kinda trigger for this? I also read some about rules for postgresql.

[Conserts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtRea.png)

Thank you for help!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your data has no obvious "time" column (because it only has "date" columns).  And it is unclear what 24 hours means in this context.

Comment: You can alter the table so it requires the field(s) to be unique. So when you try to insert a duplicate row the database will throw an error. And handle such an error in your code. In java it's a try-catch. Other languages have similar constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "24 hours" you mean "calendar date", then you simply need a unique constraint:

```
alter table concerts add constraint unq_concerts_bands
    unique (bandid, startdate);
```

If the startdate is a timestamp, you can use a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_concerts_bands on concerts(bandid, date_trunc('date', startdate));
```

Comment: Will it work even when using timestamp? I mean the timestamp have time and date.

Comment: @Ludvig Isn't the timestamp is just a number?

Comment: It looks like this 2020-02-11 18:01:00, timestamp without time zone.

Comment: the unique index sounds like something very easy and good to use. However I get a syntax error over at the :: just before date. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Tried it this way and it's working good:

create unique index unq_concerts_bands on 
piljetter_system.conserts(bandid, date_trunc('day',startdate));

Comment: @Ludvig . . . That should work as well.  I'm surprised the `::` conversion doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question makes it clear to me you are not talking about calendar days, but actual 24 hour time intervals.  You can preclude this using an EXCLUDE constraint.  Since you are storing a timestamp, not a range, in the table, you will have to dynamically create the range from the timestamp for it to be used in the constraint.

```
create extension btree_gist ;
alter table concerts add constraint blah exclude using gist 
    (band_id with =, tsrange(starttime, starttime+interval '24 hours') with &&);
```

Comment: This sounds like a nice way of doing it, however I get syntax error over at with =
Anything that is missing in your code above?

Comment: I think I've spelled my demo columns differently than you did, but that shouldn't give a syntax error.  What version of PostgreSQL are you using?